# Constructing polynomial of lowest degree

Tags: polynomials

Construct a polynomial of lowest degree with rational coefficients, one of whose roots is $\sin(20^{\circ})$. [I am able to obtain a polynomial of degree 6 but how do I know it is of lowest degree]

Comment: What is your polynomial of degree $6$?

Comment: Is this polynomial irreducible? If yes then it should be the minimal polynomial of the field extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sin(20^\circ))/\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: It's 64x^6 - 96x^4 + 36x^2 - 3

Comment: Are you familiar with Eisenstein's criterion?

Comment: No I do not know

Comment: Then you need to find another way to check for irreducibility. One that comes to mind is to use the substitution $y=x^2$, factor the resulting polynomial over $\mathbb{R}$, and deduce that it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ from the uniqueness of factorization.

Comment: I would suggest reading the Wikipedia article on [Eisenstein's Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion). The proof is not too difficult and its methodology is instructive. Then you can apply it here.

Comment: I have written a detailed answer to your question providing you with another way to show that your polynomial is irreducible without knowing Eisenstein's Criterion along with a proof of why it enough to show that it is irreducible. As @robjohn said, however, Eisenstein's Criterion is very useful and is worth learning it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments the polynomial found by the OP is
$$f(x) = 64x^6 - 96x^4 + 36x^2 - 3$$
What the question asks in other words is to show that the degree of the field extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sin20^\circ)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is 6. This is guaranteed if we show that $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. To see why this is true suppose that there exists another polynomial $g(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ with minimal degree such that $g(\sin 20^\circ) = 0$ and $\deg g(x) < \deg f(x)$. Then we could divide $f(x)$ by $g(x)$ and get
$$f(x) = q(x)g(x) + r(x), \;\; q(x),r(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x] \text{ and } \deg r(x) < \deg g(x)$$
Then $r(x) = f(x) - q(x)g(x)$ and substituting $x=\sin 20^{\circ}$ we get $r(\sin 20^{\circ})=0$, contradicting the minimality of $g(x)$. Therefore $f(x)$ is indeed a lowest degree polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ with $\sin 20^\circ$ as a root.

The standard way to show that $f(x)$ is indeed irreducible is to use [Eisenstein's Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion). In this case, we can apply it for $p = 3$ and get the desired result. Since the OP is not familiar with this criterion I am providing an outline of an alternate way to prove that $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. First, verify using the rational root theorem that this polynomial has no rational roots. Then, introduce the substitution $y= x^2$ to get to a 3rd degree polynomial. Now you can use some methods from analysis (IVT, derivatives) to prove that this polynomial has exactly  3 distinct positive real roots and conclude that $f(x)$ has 6 distinct real roots that aren't rational. This means that we can write
$$f(x) = \prod_{i=1}^6 (x-a_i), \;\; a_i \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$$
From the uniqueness of factorization over the reals $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.